# How to avoid inserting duplicate records in table type sql server for a simple table with two rows key-1 and key-2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a simple table with two columns, let's say Id-1 and Id-2.

The combination must be unique, but that is solved because they are together the primary key.

So 1,1 1,2 1,3 is taken care of.

But how can I avoid the combinations 2,1 and 1,2 and 1,3 and 3,1 that are not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two other columns that are computed based on the lowest value of the first column, then put a unique index on those two computed columns.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test1](
    [ID1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID1A]  AS (case when [ID1]<[ID2] then [ID1] else [ID2] end),
    [ID2A]  AS (case when [ID1]>[ID2] then [ID1] else [ID2] end),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Test1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID1A] ASC,
    [ID2A] ASC
)
```